# How to style google Map.Place.AutoComplete result?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I have no idea , how to style google map result ?

BY using below code  i am able to get result [Mapimage](http://s10.postimg.org/tx4ngp5g9/Capture2.png)

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

<script>

function f() {

var origin_input = document.getElementById('addr');
var autocomplete_origin = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(origin_input);    
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', f);
</script>

<body>
<input id="addr" type="text" onchange="f()">
</body>
```

But i want like this [image](http://s8.postimg.org/4034h21d1/Capture2.png) , How to achieve this ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?csw=1

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the result you want on a **JSBIN DEMO**: http://jsbin.com/qukofi/1/edit

Do you see the same? Maybe it depends on location.

[image: Demo image]

**EDIT:** So problem was that **it doesn't work locally**. It must be tried on localhost or a real server. And just so anybody who reads this knows, it doesn't show the "powered by Google" in IE8 and below. It just doesn't work. It works fine on all the modern browsers.

Comment: I am not getting on my windows , What's problem is there ? I tried in all browser opera  , webkit ,mozilla .In jsbin It's look is  same as i want , but result is not same on my windows .

Comment: Check the jsbin again. I've forced the image via CSS. Maybe it'd work this way. It's weird but it must work now.

Comment: Problem may be due to Domain . Since i am using file system .

Comment: I got solution , This is not working locally , You have to host your file to running server .

Comment: But you weren't getting on jsbin neither, were you? I tested it on all browsers and found out it just doesn't work on IE8. IE9+ and all modern browsers are getting it just fine :)

Comment: No in JSbin it's working but on my windows locally it's not working .